# Getting "Glyph not available" error when using apache fop with updated linux kernel

Tags: linux, apache-fop

I am using apache fop 2.0 for .png generation. I have specified font directory in 'fop factory' creation. Font directory contains three font files for font (say font is x and files are x.ttf, x.pfb, x.pfm). Configuration file specifies  property. This configuration used to work fine until I update my linux kernel. It started throwing error "Glyph not available" for some character, as a result final .png file generated was garbled. I fixed this issue by manually specifying the mapping to the font as

```
<font embed-url="x.ttf">
        <font-triplet name="x" style="normal" weight="normal" />
</font>
```

in fop configuration file. But I want to know why it stopped finding glyph representation with new kernel version. Can anybody help me find the reason for this problem?